# Display error on actionProductUpdate hook execution

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Is there any way to display an error message after `actionProductUpdate` hook is executed in a module?

Looking at the Prestashop code, the hook is triggered in `AdminProductController`, but the return value is not being processed. Also adding any message in passed `Product` object seems to be out of my requirement.

The purpose is to provide user with an error message in case of wrong input, database update error etc after clicking on Save button in back-office product edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in belvg blog user Prestarocket post the the very helpful comment:

"Why not using hookActionProductSave ?
With this hook, you can add errors to the controller ($this->context->controller->errors[])"

Regards

Comment: AS far as I know `actionProductSave` and `actionProductUpdate` hooks are similar. Anyway thanks for your answer, can't believe I forget that the context object has link to current controller.